# Проблема со строками PYTHON

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Работаю с api.vk, в переменную записывается текст из последнего сообщения, нужно достать баланс:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите, как это сделать.. + он может быть бесконечным (1,000,000,000,000,000) имеет такой вид, желательно чтоб на выходе был без запятых, только цифры.
Получается, мне нужно достать цифры из второй строки.

+код и выход
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import vk
import time
import random

token = "" #Сюда вводим свой токен.

session = vk.Session(access_token = token)
api = vk.API(session, v = "5.95")

a=api.messages.getHistory(peer_id=-173401327, offset=0, count=1)
bal = a['items'][0]['text']
print(bal)
```

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, входные данные в текстовом виде

Answer (score 0):

1. Находишь вхождение `\$\s*:\s*([0-9,]+)` и берёшь первую группу.
2. Удаляешь запятые.
3. Приводишь к int'у.

Comment: Прощу прощения, но я ничего не понял(

Answer (score 0):

```py
# модуль регулярных выражений
import re

# компилируем регулярку
r = re.compile(r'([\d,]+)')
# [] - один из символов, \d - любая цифра, + - 1 или более вхождений шаблона слева,
# () - группировка выхода, "," - должен быть символ запятой
# символы для удаления
letters = ','

# входной текст
text = '1,000,000'
# ищем по регулярке
i = r.findall(text)
# берем 1 вхождение
i = i[0]
# проходим циклом по строке letters
for l in letters:
    i = i.replace(l, '')  # заменяем символ из letters на пустую строку
# приводим к цифре
i = int(i)
# выводим результат
print(i)
# выход: 1000000
```

Написал как можно подробней. Хорошее описание модуля `re` есть [здесь](https://tproger.ru/translations/regular-expression-python/).